# Combine 2 Jira JQL querys Epic and Subtask

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jql

I try to find a solution to seach all subtasks from all issues inside an epic.
How to find the epics and finaly how to query the single epics I have no problem with.

1.) Get all Epics for fixed Version:

```
http://jira.mynet.local:8080/rest/api/latest/search?jql=project=ONE+AND+type+in+(%27Epic%27)+and+fixVersion=%27M123%27
```

2.) finaly I loop through the result and collect all subtasks for the single epic.

```
http://jira.osc.local:8080/rest/api/latest/search?jql=project=ONE+AND+issue+IN+subtasksOf(%27Epic+Link%27=%27myEpic1%27)
```

I think there must also one call possible. So I tried to select the subtasks from all epics with:

```
http://jira.osc.local:8080/rest/api/latest/search?jql=project=ONE+AND+issue+IN+subtasksOf(issue+in+type+in+(%27Epic%27)+and+fixVersion=%27M123%27)
```

I tried different configurations but Jira do not like my idea. So an I hope to get an idea how to select all subtasks from all storys in all epics from fixed version?

Answer (score 0):

I you have scriptrunner installed, you can do this with the following simple JQL:

```
issueFunction in subtasksOf("\"epic link\" = Epic-Link-Key")
```